# How to convert a SortedSet in Java to a Seq in Scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-collections, sortedset

The Jedis call I'm using returns a Set, although at runtime it is actually a LinkedHashSet. I want to pull it into Scala, deserialize the elements, and return a Seq.

Answer (score 3):

Easy!

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val theJavaSet = methodReturningLinkedHashSet()
theJavaSet.asScala.toSeq
```

I'd also tend to avoid `JavaConversions` (unless restricted by an older version of Scala).  `JavaConverters` offers more control, and is immune from a couple of problems that can occur in more complicated scenarios.

Comment: Do you mean `collection.JavaConverters._`?

Comment: `error: value ScalaConverters is not a member of package collection` (on [Simply Scala](http://www.simplyscala.com/) anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Like Kevin says but without the typo, on 2.8.1 or later:

```
val javaSet: java.util.Set[String] = new java.util.LinkedHashSet[String]()
javaSet.add("a")
javaSet.add("b")
import collection.JavaConverters._
javaSet.asScala.toSeq
// res2: Seq[String] = ArrayBuffer(a, b)
```

or (also works on 2.8.0):

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
javaSet.toSeq
```